# Problem of loading ubuntu 14.04 32 bit alongside windows 8 pro 32 bit

Tags: dual-boot

I had Windows 7 64 bit installed in my laptop and I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 that time alongside Windows 7. After that I have upgraded my Ubuntu as 14.04 32 bit and It was working properly.

2/3 days ago I needed to install Windows again as it was affected by virus. This time I installed Windows 8 Pro 32 bit in my hard disk. But after installing the Windows 8, I can't see the dual boot menu from which I can go for Ubuntu 14.04 which I had earlier.

In this case how can I recover my Ubuntu along with the dual boot menu to use both Ubuntu 14.04 Lts 32 bit & Windows 8 Pro 32 bit together without reinstalling the Ubuntu.

Comment: You must switch off secure boot, fast boot run boot-repair and all that! Seriously its not so easy installing Ubuntu alongside windows 8 as the latter made it so. Just refer to this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8  will overwrite GRUB boot menu(which is the dual boot screen you are referring to). I believe reinstalling GRUB through windows will fix your problem. Another fix would be simply to reinstall Ubuntu, in which process you can reinstall GRUB and decide between Windows OS and Ubuntu. It is possible to retain your previous Ubuntu files this way. I would first try installing GRUB boot menu and making sure it is installed on the root of the first partition. I am not an expert but I believe this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you reinstalled windows , GRUB boot menu would have disapeared ,You can get it back , Just follow these steps.

1. Boot your system with live Ubuntu Disc
2. Once you boot into your Ubuntu , open terminal and type the following.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair- trusty.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
   ```
3. This will install and start Boot-Repair.
4. Select "Recommended Repair"
5. Let it complete and Reboot once the process is complete.On your reboot , you will see GRUB boot menu appear with Windows as well as Ubuntu.

For more information click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).